# MySQL. How do I UPDATE the last record retrieved

Tags: mysql

I want to do a sequential read of a MySQL table, without a single identifier. Also, I want to assign a correlative number to the first column of each record. What instructions should be used for UPDATE?

Thank you so much.

Comment: sequential ? how are you identifying sequence? Please add sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using multi table update syntax (ie join) and row_number window function

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T
(DATES DATE, TODA INT);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2021-04-04',1),('2021-04-05',1);

update t join
(select dates,row_number() over (order by dates) rn 
from t) u
on t.dates = u.dates
set toda = rn
where 1 = 1;

select * from t; 

+------------+------+
| DATES      | TODA |
+------------+------+
| 2021-04-04 |    1 |
| 2021-04-05 |    2 |
+------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```